# How to kill an unknown jps process

Tags: process, kill

I am receiving this result when I practice hadoop in my centos 7 on VMware: (I already searched but still couldn't sort it out, sorry, I am new to hadoop)

right after I start my vm and login as root, and I run jps to do some check before I start my work, I see this result:

[image]

I already tried reboot, restart, format the namenode, the process is still there. I checked with ps-ef, I don't see a matched id.

During my use of centos, I've always been using root account, I know it is not a good practice, I just want to avoid all the privilege limitation.

So can anyone tell me how to kill this process? where does the process reside? how to find the root cause?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with more googlings, here is the way to resolve it:

There is a folder /tmp, go there and look for another folder like hsperfdata_xxxx where xxxx is the user name, just double check whatever user you created and do this:

ls -l hsper*

In my case it shows me:

[image]

So go ahead and delete the file, bingo, no more the unavailable process message.

I hope this helps.

Thank you.